# Excel vba macro to download a file automatically when it's added to a Sharepoint site

Tags: vba, excel, sharepoint

I am running an excel macro, it downloads some files from SharePoint. It's working fine but my problem is, Everytime i need to check if the file exists there or no then i download it.

Is there a possibility to add a condition when the file is added on SharePoint then the macro will run automatically. Because the reports are uploaded in different times by other users for example one day at 9 am, another day 11 am, another day at 1pm... and now i am checking everyday many times on the sharepoint site if the report was added or no before i run my macro.

I want to avoid this and link somehow the sharepoint site to my macro. 
For example for the reports i receive on Outlook i created a macro when i receive an email with attachment containing a specific name it will download automatically. I want something similar on Sharepoint without checking everytime on Sharepoint if the other users uploaded their reports or not.

Any suggestion please ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using SharePoint 2013 OnPremise you can write an ItemAdded event receiver which will execute your macro (you can do this only if you are allowed to deploy code to SharePoint).

You could also write a Service / Job that will run every 5-10 minutes and check which files have been added in the last 5-10 minutes (this frequency will depend on what is the urgency for executing the macro), download the file and then execute the macro on those.

Irrespective of the environment this code could run directly from your local machine if you have no good place to host it.